# Android - Can't resolve symbol action_add_task

Tags: android

i try to follow on tutorial for making simple ToDoList , after all i create somehing like this: 
    package sk.melnikovic.michal.todolist;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

import sk.melnikovic.michal.todolist.db.TaskContract;
import sk.melnikovic.michal.todolist.db.TaskDBHelper;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TaskDBHelper helper;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = new TaskDBHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
                null,null,null,null,null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("MainActivity cursor",
                    cursor.getString(
                            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                                    TaskContract.Columns.TASK)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_task:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Add a task");
                builder.setMessage("What do you want to do?");
                final EditText inputField = new EditText(this);
                builder.setView(inputField);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String task = inputField.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("MainActivity",task);

                        TaskDBHelper helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                        values.clear();
                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.TASK,task);

                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TABLE,null,values,
                                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

                builder.create().show();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_add_task"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="Add Task" />

</menu>
```

It looks pretty cool for me, atleast cool for someone who is beginer in android APP and in general this is my first try.

HOw ever i get error "Can't resolve symbol action_add_task" in my .class, I have no idea why i am getting that, and i have no idea how can I fix that because i think i try all i can.

Is here some nice person who can show me the right way how to do that? I mostly look for some explenation of my mystake to learn from it and not do it again (if it's possible)

Thanks for reading this

Comment: Did you try to clean your project? (`gradle clean` or `mvn clean` or clean through Eclipse)

Comment: I did mate, nothing happened. After I did it i get same error on eah R.